# Reading a specific data type from a line in a text file

Tags: java

I'm trying to work out the average number of items from a list of insurance policies, how do I get the value of only the items(int) from a text file?

Here is an example of data in the text file:

```
20-Jul-2017   EQ123B   3   40000   30   A   5389   l a   
20-Jul-2017   ED423A   2   40000   30   A   5389   k d   
31-Jul-2017   ZD123V   4   40000   30   A   5389   s c
```

---

Each line represents data for a different insurance policy, with the third column being the amount of items to be insured. I had planned to get the average number of items per policy by getting the total amount of items in the file and dividing that by the number of policies.

Here is my code so far:

```
    try{
        int numOfPolicies = 0;
        try (Scanner file = new Scanner(new FileReader("policy.txt"))) {

            //loop through the file counting each line. Each line represents a policy
            while(file.hasNextLine()){

                numOfPolicies++;
                file.nextLine(); 
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Total Number of Policies: " + numOfPolicies);

    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){

        System.out.println("File not found");
    }
```

---

As you can see I have already got the number of policies in the file. How do I read only the number of items from each line, and store this in a variable?

Comment: Try a regex with a capturing group, which will give you only the number

Comment: what do you want to get, which number?

Comment: @YCF_L the third element of each line, e.g 3 in the first line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your lines follow this format (whitespace used only as separator) :

```
20-Jul-2017 EQ123B 3 40000 30 A 5389 l a
```

To retrieve `3`, you could capture the number between the second and the third whitespace.
You could use the `String.split()` method with the `\\s` regex and a limit of `4` as you don't care token after the number of policies :

```
String[] split = file.nextLine().split("\\s+", 4);
```

You will get the following token :

> 20-Jul-2017
>
> EQ123B
>
> 3
>
> 40000 30 A 5389 l a

You could get so the third token :

```
String number = split[2];
```

Comment: what would the 's' be in 's.split...'? do I need to set that String to equal the whole line?

Comment: The `s` is the read line. I updated. You may not read the whole line by using a `BufferedReader` instead of Scanner and by reading with a "little" buffer by using `read(char cbuf[], int off, int len)`